# d3.stack(), Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, stack

When I execute this code I will receive an error, this error is: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGLB0.png)

I am not really familiar with the d3.stack() function, so i have no idea how to debug it. Is there a fix for this error?

This is the console.log() of filtered_data: [filtered_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDBwY.png). Each of the objects consist of the same five boroughs of New York.

```
 <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  d3.csv("Air_Quality.csv", function (airquality_data) {

  var variabelen = ["PM2.5-Attributable Deaths ", "O3-Attributable Asthma ED Visits", "O3-Attributable Asthma Hospitalizations "];
  var filtered_data = {};
  for (j = 0; j < variabelen.length; j++) {
    var variable = variabelen[j]
    var data = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < airquality_data.length; i++) {
      if (airquality_data[i].name == variabelen[j] && airquality_data[i].geo_type_name == "Borough" && airquality_data[i].year_description == "2005-2007") {
        var key = airquality_data[i].geo_entity_name;
        var value = airquality_data[i].data_valuemessage;
        data[key] = value;
    }
}
    filtered_data[variable] = data;


  var stack = d3.stack()
      .keys("Bronx", "Brooklyn", "Staten Island", "Queens", "Manhattan")
      .order(d3.stackOrderNone)
      .offset(d3.stackOffsetNone);

  var series = stack(filtered_data);

  console.log(series);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution had been found, forgot to add brackets in .keys() and had to alter filtered_data slightly.